# Unable to start Peers in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I created crypto material and channel artifacts for a network using Hyperledger Fabric. Then I Up the network but it only up the cli container. Then I look for the logs in the containers. In all peers, it shows me like this.

```
Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory
```

In orderer container,

```
Failed to initialize local MSP: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: stat /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory
```

I tried and searched a lot to find a solution to this problem. But I was unable to find any reason for this problem. Yesterday It was working fine without any errors but today when I restarted the network it leaves me with these errors. Can someone help me solve this problem?. Thank you!

Comment: check the volume mapping in docker-compose.yml file and if the file path is correct. in volumes check the path - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer

Comment: @Harshit but they are correct.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Windows 7 or Windows 10?

Comment: @GariSingh I am using windows 10

Comment: And using Docker for Windows?  The issue here might be that you have not properly enabled folder sharing with Docker for Windows

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error popping up, and I discovered that for some reason the volumes mapping probably wasn't correct.

You may want to double check that the MSP path mapping in the volumes refers to the /msp folder of the actual entity, and not on the level of OrdererOrganizations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try using 'Teardown Fabric Runtime' and start it again.

The problem was that the first time I started fabric on Windows 10, I haven't enabled C drive sharing in Docker and got error:

`C: drive is not shared. Please share it in Docker for Windows Settings.`

Then I turned C drive sharing on and it resolved drive sharing error, however I started getting the error you mentioned. All I did was teared down fabric and started it again. I guess it's related to false start of fabric docker containers and all it needs is a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue by turn off firewall my Firewall was blocking, sharing drive with docker hence docker was not able to read certificate from given location **"could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts"** . try this any reply me if get success .